# Are colMeans(), colSums()... in R also parallelized?

Tags: c, r, performance, parallel-processing

We know that using functions like `colMeans()`, `colSums()` is a lot faster than their equivalent using `apply()`, as this are precompiled (in `C`, `C++`...?)

Are these functions also automatically parallelized in these languages?

Maybe it does not really make sense the overhead cost of parallelizing as it is only a very simple function, Right? But still, for very large matrices it could make sense?

Comment: If you type `colMeans` (with no `()`) in the console, you'll see the R code for it. The actual work takes place in a couple of function calls which start `.Internal(colMeans`, which is a clear indication that a compiled C function which is built into the R interpreter is being invoked. Since R is open source, you could look up the code for that function if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is automatically parallelized in R, however these exact functions exist in the `Rfast` package with a parallel argument.

Comment: Does it actually make sense to parallelize these?

Comment: @D1X Maybe, if your dimensions are too damn hiiiigh.

Answer (score 3):

Even without parallelization the Rfast implementation is better.

```
x = matrix(rnorm(1000*100),ncol=100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(.colSums(x,1000,100), colSums(x),Rfast::colsums(x,parallel=0),times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                          expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq     max    neval
         .colSums(x, 1000, 100) 124.870 125.725 127.28580 125.726 126.153 301.911  1000
                     colSums(x) 132.567 133.423 136.30507 134.705 135.134 282.668  1000
Rfast::colsums(x, parallel = 0)  79.541  80.824  84.00742  81.252  82.107 307.470  1000
```

Bigger matrixes make parallelization relevant (benchmarks from 2 core laptop)

```
x = matrix(rnorm(1000*1000),ncol=1000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(.colSums(x,1000,1000), colSums(x),Rfast::colsums(x,parallel=0),
    Rfast::colsums(x,parallel=1),times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                           expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max  neval
        .colSums(x, 1000, 1000) 1313.268 1336.3600 1366.5152 1344.486 1355.1760 2468.310  1000
                     colSums(x) 1350.473 1366.2950 1401.0574 1374.420 1386.8210 2826.241  1000
Rfast::colsums(x, parallel = 0)  755.205  769.7440  801.5617  779.152  796.6850 1796.068  1000
Rfast::colsums(x, parallel = 1)  604.249  637.8185  680.3327  651.289  674.1675 1808.042  1000

x = matrix(rnorm(100000*100),ncol=100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(.colSums(x,100000,100), colSums(x),Rfast::colsums(x,parallel=0),
    Rfast::colsums(x,parallel=1),times=1000)

 Unit: milliseconds
                            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq     max    neval
         .colSums(x, 1e+05, 100) 12.910733 12.971671 13.124897 13.011441 13.087346 26.914502  1000
                      colSums(x) 12.944944 13.012511 13.142074 13.058268 13.128400 14.879138  1000
 Rfast::colsums(x, parallel = 0)  6.988414  7.009796  7.165310  7.068810  7.154765 16.826589  1000
 Rfast::colsums(x, parallel = 1)  4.061679  4.251977  4.373995  4.296451  4.385827  7.610196  1000
```

Comment: Note that there is also `base::.colSums()` which comes with less overhead than `base::colSums()`.

Comment: @HenrikB As you can see in the updated benchmarks, the overhead difference between base::.colSums() and base::colSums() is insignificant, comparing to how little time it takes for Rfast to compute the same results